# Does a ChronoPay extension exist for Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

Reading some [official document](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/solutions-by-region.html) it appears that **Magento supports ChronoPay payment gateway**, but there is no evidence in source code or backend of Magento 1 CE.

Magento Connect and Google aren't helping either.

The only pseudo-extension I found is something embedded in a custom [Magento Russian Edition](http://magento-forum.ru/topic/499/) that is sold under a proprietary license.

Is it just a matter of outdated/wrong documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's interesting, Magento CE does not support ChronoPay out of the box that's for sure.

I don't know why this official doc says so though.

The only thing I've managed to find is this deprecated Magento Connect link that seems to be related to a ChronoPay extension but I can't tell if it's outdated, official or anything else: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_Chronopay/1.1.1/Mage_Chronopay-1.1.1.tgz

The link does not work so I assume the extension is not on Magento Connect anymore.